# QGIS 3.4 - In Layout View can I use the properties of one item as a variable in an expression for another item?

Tags: qgis, layouts, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

In my layouts I have a legend and a references text box. I want the references text box to be next to the legend in every layout however the width of the legend changes often. Both items are in the bottom right corner of the layout.

Both items' position reference point is bottom right. To position the references box correctly each time I take the X position of the legend, subtract the width of the legend, and then subtract the distance I want between them. The result is the X position of the references box.

Instead of doing this manually can I use an expression like this for the X position of the references box:

```
"Legend_X" - "Legend_Width" - 5
```